# VB.Net - Is there any way run the vb.net application on windows 7 pro 64x bit that I have developed on windows 10 Pro 64x bit

Tags: .net, vb.net, deployment, clickonce

just want to ask if there is still a way to run the application on windows 7 pro that I have developed on windows 10 pro. After I published the vb.net application, I tried to install it using ClickOnce on windows 10 pro and it's running without any problems. But when I tried to run the application on windows 7 pro, it's not working and I am receiving the error, please see the image below.

[image]

And I also tried to download Latest .Net framework on windows 7 pro, but It cannot be installed. Also I tried to downgrade the application's .Net Framework from 4.5 to 3.0 and I'm getting a lot of errors due to the frameworks that I used to develop the app. What can you suggest to run the application?

Your answer is very much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Well not to state the obvious, and probably making an assumption the problem is actually Windows 7 comparability.  As much as I liked windows 7 it's dead,  upgrade to win 10.  Also check the Build config.  Are you deploying a 64bit app to 32bit windows?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.8 can be installed in Windows 7 without any problem. If you can't, then that machine has more than one issue. It has probably never been updated. Or it's even missing the service pack.

Comment: @Hursey Nope, its 64bit to 64bit. I already tried to run it on 32 bit its still not running.

Comment: BTW, you cut out from the Watson buckets the `Problem` 8 and 9 (7 is barely visible), which is the information that matter most, if you want to use `ildasm.exe` to determine the offset (8) of the method (7) that caused the exception described at (9). -- You're probably not handling and logging `AppDomain.UnhandledException`.